# Web API connection string to multiple databases

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

We have web application designed in VS2008. When adding some new functionality we are trying to use Web API.

In the existing system, each user from a client has access to their database. So, when a user logs in, we pull the connection string and save it in a session. Every insert, Update or select that the user performs, it uses the connection string in the session and when the user logs out, it gets cleared out.

How do I achieve this functionality if I have to use a Web API in this scenario?

Can I pass the connection string to Web API for every request?

The only other way I could think of is after every request to Web API, I have to connect to database and get the connection string based on the `UserID` that I have. This would add one extra step of connecting to database for every request.

Is there any other way?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: It's called *caching*. If you don't care about live updates, read all the possible connex from the db on application start and shove it into a cache. If you care about live updates, use a MemoryCache and set the expiry to whatever you want.

Comment: Thanks. This worked.